# Are some motherboard brands, per se, of lower quality?

Tags: motherboard

I have heard in different occasions that some motherboard brands (such as PC Chips and ASRock) are cheap, in both senses: less expensive and of lower quality, because the manufacturers use components that don't reach certain standars and/or have been discarded from assembly lines with higher standars (like ASrock that would be a cheap line from Asus).

Are these affirmations true or complete nonsense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Per se** lower quality?  No.

There are lines which produce very cheap motherboards. I suspect (-with no hard evidence to back that up!-) that most use cheaper components.

However things get quite muddled at the cheaper end. E.g. consider the Cyrix 200+ CPU. Sold very cheap compared to the pentium-1. Often found in desktops with the cheapest possible power supplies, the cheapest possible motherboards, the cheapest possible graphics cards... and often in an unstable system.

Unsurprisingly it had a very bad name, yet one ran without problems for years in an old Asus boards with good hardware.

The point of that anecdote is to point out that *a* piece of cheap hardware can be worse quality, but it does not have to be. And that mouth to mouth experience in this case is often wrong.

Having said that: Your motherboard is the backplane of all other components. Both on add-in cards or integrated. Getting a good motherboard is worth it. So do read reviews of which board you are considering, but do so with a critical eye.

Comment: For what it's worth, a motherboard could have good components but bad design.  We bought a slew of the same ASUS monterhboards and all had the exact same problem; the math processor and CPU were too close together and wasn't properly disapating heat using it's heat sink.  The math processor gave out within 2 years and ASUS started offering fans as a fix.  I say all that to second Hennes's remarks... do you research.

Answer (score 0):

That is true. Many manufacturers use low grade components especially capacitors, power ics, resistor. They will rarely last a year, giving rise to vague problems, like hanging, operating system not loading, restarting, blue screen of death, etc. Stick to top brands using high grade capacitors and components only.